# How to insert data using PDO and PHP safely?

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I've been looking around a bit on different ways of inserting data into a database table, and I am not sure which one is the right/best/most secure way of doing it.

I have a form input in which a user can enter some data. I have the variables:

`$name = "Steve";`, `$password = "abc123";`, `$ip = "1.1.1.1";` and `$admin = 0;`

The way I currently insert this data into the table is as following:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip, admin) VALUES ('$name', '$password', '$ip', '$admin')";
$query = $db->prepare($q);
$result = $query->execute();
```

What improvements would you make? And why? I've seen a few put `:name` instead of `$name`. But when I did that, it literally inserted ":name" into the database, and not the actual name of the person.

Comment: You should bind variables to [prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's quite right still. You do want to use the `:name` method. The reason it inserted that literally was because you missed something on the execute, the array that tells it what values to bind to what parameters.

It should be:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip, admin) VALUES (:name, :password, :ip, :admin)";
$query = $db->prepare($q);
$result = $query->execute(array(":name" => $name, ":password" => $password, ":ip" => $ip, ":admin" => $admin));
```

As for why: It will let them handle the correct binding and sanitizing of parameters, regardless of their type.

Comment: Would this apply to anything like SELECT and UPDATE as well? And always make an array like `":name" => $name`

Comment: For example: `$sql = "UPDATE people SET country = '$country_id' WHERE name = '$name'";` should be `$sql = "UPDATE people SET country = ':country_id' WHERE name = ':name'";`

Comment: @TyhaiMahy, yes, all your statements should use it. It's much safer. Anywhere you want to use a variable, you should use the `:name` and `array(":name" => $name)` method. You shouldn't manually wrap them in quotes though, that will be handled for you when it detects it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the code listed below:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
$stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3, ':field4' => $field4, ':field5' => $field5));
```

[Full PDO reference](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)